# Primefaces : Captcha id not visible but displays validation message

Tags: primefaces, captcha, recaptcha

I'm using Primefaces `captcha` to fortify my authentication process, i followed every step there is to make it work including the generation of the public and private keys, but still it didn't work.

The problem is that the `captcha` **is not visible** but it's preventing authentication by displaying a validation message at the same time.
[image]

**Here is the code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    lang="#{languageSwitcher.locale}"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:define name="title">
    <h:outputText value="Please Sign In" />
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Please Sign In" />
</ui:define>

<h:head>
    <title>Connexion</title>

    <!--     <meta charset="utf-8" /> -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/images/icons/dataprotect.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Thu, 19 Nov 1900 08:52:00 GMT" />
    <!--Loading bootstrap css-->

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/file3.css" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/file1.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/vendors/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!--Loading style vendors-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/vendors/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/vendors/iCheck/skins/all.css" />
    <!--Loading style-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/themes/style1/pink-blue.css"
        class="default-style" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/themes/style1/pink-blue.css"
        id="theme-change" class="style-change color-change" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/style-responsive.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
        href="${request.contextPath}/resources/images/favicon.ico" />
<!-- background:#eeeeee !important; -->
<style>
#signin-page{
background:white !important;
}

/* .header-content{ */
/* background:#eeeeee !important; */
/* } */


</style>
</h:head>

<body id="signin-page">

    <h:form style="float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 0px;">
        <p:commandLink action="#{languageSwitcher.changeLanguage2('en')}" ajax="false" onclick="PF('enCours2').show();" oncomplete="PF('enCours2').hide();" >
            <img src="${request.contextPath}/resources/images/imgs/en.png" />

        </p:commandLink>
        <p:commandLink ajax="false" onclick="PF('enCours2').show();" oncomplete="PF('enCours2').hide();" action="#{languageSwitcher.changeLanguage2('fr')}">
            <img src="${request.contextPath}/resources/images/imgs/fr.png" />

        </p:commandLink>
        <p:commandLink ajax="false" onclick="PF('enCours2').show();" oncomplete="PF('enCours2').hide();" action="#{languageSwitcher.changeLanguage2('ar')}">
            <img src="${request.contextPath}/resources/images/imgs/ma.png" />

        </p:commandLink>


    </h:form>
    <div class="page-form">

        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <div class="header-content">
                <h1>
                 <p:graphicImage style="width:45%;"
                value="/resources/images/sensipro_dp.png" />
                </h1>
            </div>
            <p:focus />
            <p:messages id="messages" />
            <div class="body-content">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{user.email}" required="true"
                            label="Email" placeholder="Identifiant" name="email"
                            requiredMessage="Identifiant ou email est requis"
                            styleClass="form-control" title="Enter your Email!" >
                            <f:validator binding="#{sizeValidator}" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        <p:message for="email" display="icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                        <h:inputSecret id="pass" placeholder="Mot de passe"
                            name="password" styleClass="form-control"
                            value="#{user.password}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Mot de passe est requis" label="Password"
                            title="Please enter a password!" >
                            <f:validator binding="#{sizeValidator}" />
                            </h:inputSecret>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <p:captcha label="Captcha" rendered="true" />


                <div class="form-group pull-left">
                    <div class="checkbox-list">
                        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" />&nbsp;
                            Se souvenir de moi
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <p:commandLink id="submitButton" styleClass="btn btn-success" ajax="false"
                        action="confirmSignIn" onsuccess="PF('enCours').hide();" onclick="PF('enCours').show();" update="messages @all">#{msg['signin']} &nbsp;<i
                            class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>

                    </p:commandLink>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="forget-password">
                    <h6>Mot de passe oublié ?</h6>

                    <p>
                        Veuillez cliquer <a
                            href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/forgottenPwd.jsf"
                            class='btn-forgot-pwd'><b>ici</b></a> pour rénitialiser votre mot de
                        passe.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>

        </h:form>
    </div>

    <p:dialog modal="true" id="guns" widgetVar="enCours" header="En cours" 
            style="position:fixed;" draggable="false" width="350px"
            height="120px" closable="false"> 
            <center>
            <p:outputPanel id="mark">
        <h:outputLabel value="Authentification en cours..."> </h:outputLabel>
             </p:outputPanel>
    <p:graphicImage
                value="/resources/vendors/pageloader/images/loader100.gif" />
                </center>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog modal="true" id="guns2" widgetVar="enCours2" header="En cours" 
            style="position:fixed;" draggable="false" width="350px"
            height="120px" closable="false"> 
            <center>
            <p:outputPanel id="mark2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Changement du langue en cours..."> </h:outputLabel>
             </p:outputPanel>
    <p:graphicImage
                value="/resources/vendors/pageloader/images/loader100.gif" />
                </center>
        </p:dialog>

</body>

</html>
```

**-- Edited --**

I'm using https implemented by spring security.

If anyone understand the problem, don't hesitate and thank you.

Comment: Did you update public&private  keys in web.xml ?

Comment: yes, i generated theme just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your captcha tag is not in set any div that's why it is not displaying for use primefaces component should be set in div or panelgrid inside form tag.
So should be use div tag and set div position  according your requirement. 
Or
 Use theme also , you are not using theme and put secure="true". It is working for me I hope it will work for you

```
<div height="50px" width="130px">
     <p:captcha label="Captcha" rendered="true" secure="true"  theme="white" > 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work, i think the problem is related to SSL protection some how, if i disable it on the browser it appears but still not working :'( ...

Comment: the problem was ssl as i tough, i posted the solution, thank you for your help ^^.

Comment: I modified my answer put secure attribute also

Comment: Oh god. You already solve this issue , sorry man my internet connection is slow and I'm using android app this time. So I delayed sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add **secure="true"** to the captcha tag.

```
   <div height="50px" width="130px">
        <p:captcha label="Captcha" rendered="true" secure="true" theme="white"/>
    </div>
```